# How To G++ compile A .cpp File With Dependencies In Another Directory

Tags: c++, directory, compilation, dependencies

My project is organized the following way:

```
mainfolder
    |
    |_main.cpp
    |
    |_subfolder
          |
          |_foo.hpp
          |_foo.cpp
          |_bar.hpp
          |_bar.cpp
```

main.cpp uses functions and variables from foo.hpp and bar.hpp, whose function implementations are in foo.cpp and bar.cpp respectively

I was wondering how I would use g++ to compile main.cpp

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to build object files, or just the executable file `main`? And where do you want the file(s) you build?

Comment: `g++ main.cpp subfolder/foo.cpp subfolder/bar.cpp -o outputname`

Answer (score 2):

You can compile main on its own like this:

`g++ -c main.cpp -Isubfolder -o main.o`

This line compiles main.cpp into an object file (not an application) but it gives it the path (`-I<paht>`) where it can fine the include files

You probably want to then also compile the other two files into objects:

`g++ -c subfolder/foo.cpp -Isubfolder -o foo.o`

`g++ -c subfolder/bar.cpp -Isubfolder -o bar.o`

Where the `-c` flag means compile only (and not link). So then you probably want to link your objects together:

`g++ main.o foo.o bar.o -o myapp`

---

Or in one line:

`g++ main.cpp subfolder/foo.cpp subfolder/bar.cpp -Isubfolder -o myapp`

The first method (to do it in two steps) is generally easier when you want to create a pattern rule to compile files (with gnu make), the second (in one line) is easier to do manually